I want to add a compatibility check for plugin that it requires Elementor
I've created a widget for elementor and now I want to add a check that it requires elementor. Even the elementor is activated the plugin still not showing the widget in elementor and keeps on showing the notice.
public function __construct()
{

  if ( ! did_action( 'elementor/loaded' ) ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', [ $this, 'admin_notice_missing_main_plugin' ] );
        return false;
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'tm_load_assets'));
     
      add_action( 'elementor/widgets/register', array($this,'register_team_member_widget' ));

     
}

public function admin_notice_missing_main_plugin() {
  if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) unset( $_GET['activate'] );

  $message = sprintf(
    /* translators: 1: Plugin name 2: Elementor */
    esc_html__( '"%1$s" requires "%2$s" to be installed and activated.', 'elementor-test-addon' ),
    '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'Team Member', 'elementor-test-addon' ) . '</strong>',
    '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'Elementor', 'elementor-test-addon' ) . '</strong>'
  );

  printf( '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible"><p>%1$s</p></div>', $message );

}

What is the best solution that if the elementor is not activated then it will show notice, and once the elementor is activated it will remove the notice, and add the widget in elementor.

Follow the dev instructions - https://developers.elementor.com/docs/addons/compatibility/
